Checking a dll content with C#
I play a game with a lot of mods. These mods come in the form of resources (images, contiguration files) as well as .dlls for C# code added or modifying the original game. The problem is that there is no mechanism to prevent conflicts between mods. Example of errors
Mods are available on the steam workshop, but some are also available on Github if you want to see an example, such as CommonSense. Dll are in 1.x/Assemblies section.
I'd like to create software that scans mod files to check a potential conflict, especially reading the .dll files to ensure that the same method is not modified by multiple mods.
So far, I can't figure out how to read the contents of a dll file “easily”.
Would you have an example of code to read a dll file or to extract its methods?

This question is similar to: How to reverse engineer an .exe that uses a .resource file to store an assembly?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Filburt The difference is that sk84z obtained the dll file and then read it manually with dotPeek. For my part, I need to read hundreds of dll files programmatically to make sure that two dlls don't modify the same method.

Finding all references to a method with Roslyn

@Filburt Your proposition is for .cs files. I struggle to open a .dll file.

Can you explain how the conflict happens?

How to browse an assembly's content without source code

@shingo Each mod adds its own elements or modifies the way the game works. Sometimes two different mods modify the same thing. For example, one mod will allow characters to have two weapons, while another mod will add hosters. In both cases, methods linked to the weapon carried will be modified, and these two mods cannot be used at the same time. In concrete terms, both mods will alter the same original game method.

The following code uses MetadataLoadContext to read all the HarmonyPatch attributes from a mod dll (CommonSense.dll) and print out the first (type) and second (method name) arguments. This may help you know which methods have been patched.
var paths = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\rimworldmod", "*.dll"));
var resolver = new PathAssemblyResolver(paths);
var mlc = new MetadataLoadContext(resolver);
var asm = mlc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"E:\rimworldmod\CommonSense.dll");
foreach(var t in asm.DefinedTypes)
{
    foreach (var cad in t.CustomAttributes)
    {
        if (cad.AttributeType.FullName == "HarmonyLib.HarmonyPatch")
        {
            var aargs = cad.ConstructorArguments;
            if (aargs.Count > 1)
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{aargs[0]} {aargs[1]}");
        }
    } 
}

Some notes:
I placed all the relevant DLLs (HarmonyMod and dlls in the package krafs.rimworld.ref) in the E:\rimworldmod directory.
Some patches, such as JobDriver_Goto_MoveNext_CommonSensePatch, which uses transpiler. The method name is declared in the method body, for this situation, you need to analyze the IL code.

Perfect! And nice explanations!
